# jQuery - drag div css background

Tags: jquery, css, background, draggable

I'd like to be able to click hold my mouse inside a div and move it's background. Searched a lot on google and didn't found what I wanted.

Here's the target (the map displayed is the object to drag) : http://pontografico.net/pvt/gamemap/

Any tips?

Cheers!

Comment: Just sketching something out, I would `onmousedown` set a `onmousemove` handler to detect and register movement and reset the `div`'s `background-image-position` settings, and then `unbind` the `mousemove` `onmouseup`. Seems reasonable?

Comment: That's what I'm doing since I wrote the question :)

Comment: If you get something working, post it as an answer. I'd be interested to see a http://jsfiddle.net working demo. `:)`

Comment: It's done, you can check the question link. I have one problem now though, how to convert mouse axys to a reasonable mousemove simulation? Probably calculate the position of the map container and subtract the values?

Comment: Register the position before you set the `mousemove` and use that as your origin. I think, too, it's possible to mark the position relevant to the element, but I'd have to look into that.

Comment: Have you looked into the draggable ui? http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: If you pass `move(e)`, `e` has `clientX` and `clientY` too.

Comment: Neither `client`, `offset` or `page` worked so far. The background is moved too fast and not accordingly to the mouse movement.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks for the effort, I'll have more problems soon tough :)

Comment: I got this close: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/q6r8f/1/ There's still some kind of rebound effect when changing direction, and the events still don't quite fire right. But it's most of the way there.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Alright, got this to work; I think I got all the kinks out:

***Final jQuery with Bounding Limits***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $bg = $('.bg-img'),
        elbounds = {
            w: parseInt($bg.width()),
            h: parseInt($bg.height())
        },
        bounds = {w: 2350 - elbounds.w, h: 1750 - elbounds.h},
        origin = {x: 0, y: 0},
        start = {x: 0, y: 0},
        movecontinue = false;

    function move (e){
        var inbounds = {x: false, y: false},
            offset = {
                x: start.x - (origin.x - e.clientX),
                y: start.y - (origin.y - e.clientY)
            };

        inbounds.x = offset.x < 0 && (offset.x * -1) < bounds.w;
        inbounds.y = offset.y < 0 && (offset.y * -1) < bounds.h;

        if (movecontinue && inbounds.x && inbounds.y) {
            start.x = offset.x;
            start.y = offset.y;

            $(this).css('background-position', start.x + 'px ' + start.y + 'px');
        }

        origin.x = e.clientX;
        origin.y = e.clientY;

        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }

    function handle (e){
        movecontinue = false;
        $bg.unbind('mousemove', move);

        if (e.type == 'mousedown') {
            origin.x = e.clientX;
            origin.y = e.clientY;
            movecontinue = true;
            $bg.bind('mousemove', move);
        } else {
            $(document.body).focus();
        }

        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }

    function reset (){
        start = {x: 0, y: 0};
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '0 0');
    }

    $bg.bind('mousedown mouseup mouseleave', handle);
    $bg.bind('dblclick', reset);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/q6r8f/4/

---

*Original Answer*

**HTML**

```
<div class="bg-img"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.bg-img {
    background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Flexopecten_ponticus_2008_G1.jpg);
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 25px auto;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $bg = $('.bg-img'),
        origin = {x: 0, y: 0},
        start = {x: 0, y: 0},
        movecontinue = false;

    function move (e){
        var moveby = {
            x: origin.x - e.clientX,
            y: origin.y - e.clientY
        };

        if (movecontinue === true) {
            start.x = start.x - moveby.x;
            start.y = start.y - moveby.y;

            $(this).css('background-position', start.x + 'px ' + start.y + 'px');
        }

        origin.x = e.clientX;
        origin.y = e.clientY;

        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }

    function handle (e){
        movecontinue = false;
        $bg.unbind('mousemove', move);

        if (e.type == 'mousedown') {
            origin.x = e.clientX;
            origin.y = e.clientY;
            movecontinue = true;
            $bg.bind('mousemove', move);
        } else {
            $(document.body).focus();
        }

        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }

    function reset (){
        start = {x: 0, y: 0};
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '0 0');
    }

    $bg.bind('mousedown mouseup mouseleave', handle);
    $bg.bind('dblclick', reset);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/q6r8f/2/

Comment: Great work! Just one last thing : how to constrain the movement to match only the background dimensions?

Comment: @DexterHuinda - I gave you credit for copying and pasting from the jQuery UI docs. Would you mind keeping your snide comments to yourself? `;)`

Comment: Well I gave you +1, didn't I? you can remove the +1 from my answer.

Comment: @yoda - You would need to calculate the offset between the dimensions of the background image and the dimensions of the container and see if you end up with a negative offset more or less. Let me see if I can incorporate that.

Comment: @DexterHuinda - You may not think it's necessary to do it any way but with UI, but what UI accomplishes isn't necessarily always what someone needs. This is an alternative and UI is perhaps the standard. "Reinvent the wheel" it is not.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Correct. In programming, there are always a thousand ways to solve a problem, so I salute you.

Comment: @yoda - Ok, here's the boundaries version: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/q6r8f/4/ You'll probably want to have a strategy for getting the `width` and `height` of the `background-image`, since you won't be able to get it directly I don't believe; you'll probably want to load it in a dummy `$('<img>').attr('src', bgurl);` and when the `load()` fires, set the bounds using that information.

Comment: @DexterHuinda - I know it was more fun to see if I could make it work than just relying on the UI method. It didn't turn out to be that difficult, and was interesting. `:)`

Comment: Thank you both for your help! I'll go with this one, since it actually does what I need. Thanks again :)

Comment: @yoda, IKR, hardcore programmers are hard to please :D

Comment: @JaredFarrish got one last question. I'm not sure where to avoid the script from moving the background. Tried an `if` right before the css background magic and it works, except that once the script reaches any of the boundaries, the axys still get calculated if we move the mouse and therefore the script doesn't match the boundaries, "freezing".

Comment: I've been looking at what you're doing; question, have you copied the last code in it's entirety and replaced what you had, and then edited it for `id` and other specific things? It looks like you're using an older version and trying to edit it up to where I ended up. Don't do that. It's tricky to get it to work; start with what's in my last fiddle link in my comments (or my edit above).

Comment: Solved, no worries. Cheers :)

Comment: @yoda - There's a few spots in there where the latest script solved one problem or the other. I've got your current page working in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/q6r8f/5/ Note, I removed the `margin-top/left` on the `gamemap_handler`, since you can and should do the same thing with the `background-position`. Getting the script to work with the margin's like that was a problem, but could probably be worked out if necessary.

Comment: @yoda - Had to fix the `height` and `width` too: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/q6r8f/6/ I imagine those were set to accommodate the jQuery UI draggable method. Is there a reason to keep that and the `margin` negative offsets?

Comment: @yoda - Also, I split the `inbounds` checks so that if you wanted to, you could change `y` when `x` was exhausted but `y` still had room to go. See: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/q6r8f/8/ and drag at angles across the edges of the map. Worked out better than I thought. `:)`

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thank you for all the effort. Yes, I think it would make a good plugin, geomaps for instance are becoming popular and tools like this are of great help :)

Comment: @yoda - It works significantly better with the separated `x, y` drag logic. Otherwise, movement jerks to a stop on an edge and you literally have to turn 90 degrees at least to continue moving.

Comment: @yoda - My last version does that, if I understand you correctly. See: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/q6r8f/8/

Comment: Yes, I noticed it after checking I was seeing the wrong version. It's great as it is now, cheers! :)

Comment: @yoda - I feel like it needs a way to signal to the user they've hit the boundary. Haven't figure out a clean way to do that.

Comment: Yes, that would be useful in a plugin context. The ability to jump / animate to a certain position would also be useful.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, Can you re-create this awesome script in jQuery UI ?

Comment: There seems to be an off-by-one error in the script on lines 22 and 23: if the picture matches exactly in one axis but should be draggable in the other, it will fail. Using <= instead of < will solve that: inbounds.x = offset.x <= 0 && (offset.x * -1) <= bounds.w;

Comment: Hi, maybe this is too late to ask, but can you help me what if I put the background-size in CSS ?, I tried it but when dragged, the background image continues to shift until the blue background is visible, thank you

Answer (score 3):

From the ui draggable demo:

Dragging DOM elements are simple, no need to reinvent the wheel.

```
<style>
#draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
</style>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    });
</script>



<div class="demo">

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->



<div class="demo-description" style="display: none; ">
<p>Enable draggable functionality on any DOM element. Move the draggable object by clicking on it with the mouse and dragging it anywhere within the viewport.</p>
</div><!-- End demo-description -->
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

EDIT: 
Draggable background inside a div is also possible. See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/FyFZA/

Comment: That's for objects, not css backgrounds.

Comment: @yoda those are for all DOM elements, may it be div, p, span, or whatever. Your background is contained inside a DOM element, so when you move a div, you moved the background contained in it.

Comment: You're not following what Yoda is doing; he's manipulating a *property* of the element (background image), not the element itself.

Comment: Despite not answering it, this post made me realize that probably I need to set a inner container inside `#gamemap`, `z-index` it and make it the navigation controller .. how does it sound?

Comment: @yoda - Here's what I have so far, it has a couple issues (my math is backward somewhere and `mouseup` doesn't always handle the unbind): http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/q6r8f/

Comment: @yoda, no problem, just edit the css, so it will fit your requirement.

Comment: I wonder how to constrain the map movement though. I'm trying with a wrapper (http://pontografico.net/pvt/gamemap/), setting the wrapper width and height as 100% more, but it isn't working at all.

Comment: @yoda fix the wrapper err the handler to the actual height and width of your image. 1123 x 794?

Comment: @yoda the `#gamemap_handler` not the wrapper.

Comment: Dexter, yoda's solution works on mobile devices too ( posting from android right now) while DOM solution doesn't. Anyway, tnx for the great work guys!

Answer (score 0):

this post was an excellent starting point for my issue. i combined the above answer, and another pertaining to getting the original dimensions of your background image ([SO:How do I get background image size in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106243/how-do-i-get-background-image-size-in-jquery))

with my particular setup i was using `background-size:cover` so i had to determine the ratio of height/width of the background image and compare it to the ratio of height/width of the container.  this means that each image is only allowed to slide in one dimension.

two extras in here you may not need. I added a border to the element I was currently manipulating just to keep it easy to see, removed it when i was done.  also I updated an input with the offset values, so i could send them onto the server.

I tend to be very verbose with my comments, so it's a little lengthy, but i hope it helps someone.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    function reset (){
        start = {x: 0, y: 0};
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '0 0');
    }

    $(".bg-img").bind('dblclick', reset);

    //my jquery
$(".bg-img").on('mousedown mouseup', function(e){

    //declare some vars
    var start = {x: 0, y: 0};
    var move = {x: 0, y: 0};
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    //pointer coordinates on mousedown
    var origin = {x: 0, y: 0};

    //container dimensions
    var container = {w: $(this).width(), h: $(this).height()};

    //container ratio
    var containerRatio = container.h / container.w;

    //background image dimensions, note: this gets dimensions of unscaled image
    var img = new Image;
    img.src = $(this).css('background-image').replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");
    var background = {w: img.width, h: img.height};

    //background ratio
    var backgroundRatio = background.h / background.w;

    //max x and y position, aka boundary
    var min = {x: 0, y: 0};
    var max = {x: 0, y: 0};

    //move x
    if(backgroundRatio < containerRatio){
        min.y = 0;
        min.x = -((container.h * (1/backgroundRatio)) - container.w);
    }

    //move y
    else if (backgroundRatio > containerRatio){
        min.x = 0;
        min.y = -((container.w * backgroundRatio) - container.h);
    }

    //ratios are equal, don't move anything
    else{
        min.x = 0;
        min.y = 0;
    }

    //activate
    if(e.type == 'mousedown'){

        //add border so it's easier to visualize
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid #000000');

        //get current position of mouse pointer
        origin.x = e.clientX;
        origin.y = e.clientY;

        //get current background image starting position
        var temp = $(this).css('background-position').split(" ");
        start.x = parseInt(temp[0]);
        start.y = parseInt(temp[1]);

        //mouse is dragged while mousedown
        $(this).mousemove(function(e){

            //move position
            move.x = start.x + (e.clientX - origin.x);
            move.y = start.y + (e.clientY - origin.y);

            //if it's in the bounds, move it
            if(move.x <= max.x && move.x >= min.x && move.y <= max.y && move.y >= min.y){

                console.log('both');

                //alter css
                $(this).css('background-position', move.x + 'px ' + move.y + 'px');

                //update input
                $("#" + id).val('x:' + move.x + ', y:' + move.y);
            }

            //in x bound,
            else if(move.x <= max.x && move.x >= min.x){

                console.log('x');

                //below min.y
                if(move.y < min.y){
                    $(this).css('background-position', move.x + 'px ' + min.y + 'px');

                    //update input
                    $("#" + id).val('x:' + move.x + ', y:' + min.y);
                }
                //above max.y
                else if(move.y > max.y){
                    $(this).css('background-position', move.x + 'px ' + max.y + 'px');

                    //update input
                    $("#" + id).val('x:' + move.x + ', y:' + max.y);
                }
            }

            //in y bound
            else if(move.y <= max.y && move.y >= min.y){

                console.log('y');

                //below min.x
                if(move.x < min.x){
                    $(this).css('background-position', min.x + 'px ' + move.y + 'px');

                    //update input
                    $("#" + id).val('x:' + min.x + ', y:' + move.y);            
                }

                //above max.x
                else if(move.x > max.x){
                    $(this).css('background-position', max.x + 'px ' + move.y + 'px');

                    //update input
                    $("#" + id).val('x:' + max.x + ', y:' + move.y);
                }
            }

            //out of both bounds
            else{
                console.log('problem');
            }
        });
    }

    //deactivate
    else{

        //remove border
        $(this).css('border', 'none');

        //remove mousemove
        $(this).off('mousemove');
        $(document.body).focus();
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but if you're using jQueryUI another solution is to create a transparent element on top of the background, then use the drag callback to update the backgroundPosition of the original node. Here's an example:

```
/* node is the element containing the background image */
/* width/height variables are just there if your background image is a different width/height then the container */
var transparent = $('<div></div>');
transparent.css({
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 10,
    left: node.offset().left,
    top: this.node.offset().top,
    width: width || node.width(),
    height: height || node.height(),
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    opacity: 0.2
});

$('body').append(transparent);

options.config.drag = function(event, ui) {
    node.css({ backgroundPosition: (ui.position.left - ui.originalPosition.left) + 'px ' + (ui.position.top - ui.originalPosition.top) + 'px' });
};

$(transparent).draggable(options.config);
```

I intentionally left a white background color with an opacity so you could see the element when testing.