# Drag Background in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I 'm new in React and i'm tryind to make draggable background, but no matter how hard I try, nothing happens. I found some code on jQuery, but there many advices that it's bad practice use jQuery in React.
Maybe i make something wrong.
Thanks in advance

Here's my React code

```
import React from "react";
import "../styles/board.css";

class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { mouseCliked: 0, startX: 0, startY: 0 };
  }

  mouseDown(e) {
    this.setState({ mouseCliked: 1, startX: e.clientX, startY: e.clientY });
  }

  mouseUp(e) {
    this.setState({ mouseCliked: 0, startX: e.clientX, startY: e.clientY });
  }

  mouseMove = (e) => {
    let newPosY = e.clientY - this.stateY;
    let newPosX = e.clientX - this.stateX;
    if (this.state.mouseClicked) {
      e.target.style.backgroundPositionX += newPosX;
      e.target.style.backgroundPositionY += newPosY;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        onMouseMove={this.mouseMove.bind(this)}
        onMouseUp={this.mouseUp.bind(this)}
        onMouseDown={this.mouseDown.bind(this)}
        className="background-image"
      >
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Board;
```

CSS:

```
    width:300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: 1000px;
    background-position-x: 0;
    background-position-y: 0;
    background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1452723312111-3a7d0db0e024?crop=entropy&dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=750&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=50&w=1450.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Do you want to drag the background image?

Comment: I want smth like this: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/q6r8f/4/

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem and also checked [jQuery - drag div css background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271704/jquery-drag-div-css-background)

Finally I came up with this solution and seemed working fine.

```
const imageStyleInitialValue = {
    backgroundImage: "",
    backgroundPosition: "0 0",
    backgroundSize: "0 0",
    height: 0,
    width: 0,
};

const [startPoint, setStartPoint] = useState({x: 0, y: 0});
const [dragging, setDragging] = useState(false);
const [imageStartPos, setImageStartPos] = useState([0, 0]);
const [imageStyles, setImageStyles] = useState<ImageStyles>(imageStyleInitialValue);

// add onMouseMove={handleDragImage} to the image component
const handleDragImage = (e) => {
    if (dragging) {
        const deltaX = e.clientX - startPoint.x;
        const deltaY = e.clientY - startPoint.y;
        setImageStyles({...imageStyles,
                        backgroundPosition:
                      `${imageStartPos[0] + deltaX} ${imageStartPos[1] + deltaY}`
        })
    }
};

// add onMouseDown={handleStartDragImage} to the image component
const handleStartDragImage = (e) => {
    setDragging(true);
    const backgroundPosArray = imageStyles.backgroundPosition.split(" ").map(value => Number(value));
    setImageStartPos(backgroundPosArray);
    setStartPoint({x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY});
}

// add onMouseUp={handleEndDragImage} to the top component because you want 
// to set Dragging to false when the dragging ends outside of the image
const handleEndDragImage = (e) => {
    setDragging(false)
};
```