# How to save the position of dragged image like facebook cover photo?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how could i save the dragged image in javascript?is there something different in code regarding to position in it? Any help would be appreciated...

```js
var imgWidth;
var imgHeight;
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://picsum.photos/860/550/?image=316';

$(img).on('load', function() {
    imgWidth = img.width;
    imgHeight = img.height;
    $('#image').css('background-image', 'url(' + img.src + ')');
}); 
var start_y;
var newPos;
var curPos = $('#image').css('background-position-y');
var mouseDown = false;
var move = true;
$('#image').mousedown( function(e) {
    mouseDown = true; 
});

$(document).mouseup( function() {
    mouseDown = false;
    $('.image').css('background-position-y', curPos)
});

$('#image').mouseenter( function(e) {
    start_y = e.clientY;
});
    
$(document).mousemove( function(e) {
    newPos = e.clientY - start_y;
    start_y = e.clientY;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div id="image"></div>
<button type="button" id="save" class="modal-add-btn">Save</button>
```

Comment: Don't tell _me_ about it. _Revise to clarify_. :)

Comment: Answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271704/jquery-drag-div-css-background.