# show background of empty span

Tags: html, css

Let's say that I have a span and I set an image as the background of the span like this:

```
<span style="background:url("my_image.png") no-repeat;"></span>
```

As you can see above, my span is empty. If I put some content in my span like:

```
<span style="background:url("my_image.png") no-repeat;">Some content...</span>
```

I can see the background image of the span with no problem. But If I leave the span empty I don't see the background image. I figured that I could solve this issue by adding some padding to my span like:

```
<span style="background:url("my_image.png") no-repeat;padding:20px;"></span>
```

But is there another way I can do this without adding some padding to my span and keep my span empty?

Thank you

Comment: The element needs to have some width and height in order for the background to be visible.  What are you trying to do? will the span ever have content?

Comment: A empty span won't be displayed. Add a padding, width / height or something else to display a empty span...

Answer (score 23):

You get the same effect by using inline-block but setting  width and height instead of using padding.

```
<span style="background:url('my_image.png') no-repeat; display: inline-block; width: 40px; height: 40px;"></span>
```

Also, something else that could trip you up is you are using double-quotes inside of an HTML attribute, which would confuse a parser and could lead to unexpected results. I've changed them to single quotes in the code I posted above, although no quotes would do just as well.

Answer (score 16):

just don't make it empty: put a 'blank' inside. There are three ways, to do that:

1. simple `space` and add style  `white-space: pre;` to it
2. [Non-breaking Space](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) `&nbsp;` or `&#160;`
3. The non plus ultra is, to let css do the trick for you:

add this style to your span:

```
 :before {
    content: "\200D";
    display:inline;
 }
```

What happens:

you add a content before (or better "in front inside") your span, that displays a [`ZERO WIDTH JOINER`](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_punctuation.asp), and your span is not empty enymore

Answer (score 5):

By default spans are inline page elements (rather than 'block' elements). This means they won't take up any more space in the page than that assigned to them—for example, if you place text in them (as you have found). To achieve what you want, you need a little CSS to define a height and width for the span, but you also need to make it a block element so that it is rendered consistently.

Alternatively, you could switch to something like a div, which is already a block element. Note however that defining a block element means it **will** take up space in your page. If you want something more dynamic consider some on-the-fly manipulation of the element with Javascript or similar.

<del>(Either way, ignore the advice elsewhere on this page about single and double quotes in HTML attributes: that is utter nonsense).</del>

Comment: It's not nonsense at all. The OP is using double quotes inside the value of an HTML attribute, which would cause premature termination of the value and invalid HTML. If I have `<div title="my name is "Bob"!"></div>`, the value for the title attribute will be "my name is ". So the OP's style attribute would end up being "background:url(", which is clearly incorrect.

Comment: Quite right, my bad. I was thinking of double / single quotes in attributes, period (i.e. not _within_ attributes). Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<span style="background:url('my_image.png') no-repeat; display:block; height: 40px;"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a `width` and `height` to show the background. When you're typing something in it you force both with the text.

```
<span style="background:url("my_image.png") no-repeat; width: 50px; height: 25px"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set a `width` and `height`.
In the following SO-Question is a tip, how to get the size of the background-image: [How do I get background-image size in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106243/how-do-i-get-background-image-size-in-jquery)