# Make a picture/background scale based on width of the browser

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how I can scale a picture or a background based on the width of the browser. Basically, I want to make it as responsive as possible and making sure that it adapts well to all browsers including Safari.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about.

Link: http://responsive.gs/. Resize the width of the browser to see the background scale.

I want to make my picture/background scale exactly as shown in that link above.

Would appreciate some help on this.

Thank you.

Comment: You can just inspect the element and see exactly how they're doing it: background: url("../images/bg-phoenix.jpg") no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;

Comment: Keep in mind that background-size: cover has poor legacy browser support. Best bet is to use a js solution if you want to support older browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `background-size:cover`, as they did:

```
body {
    background: url("http://responsive.gs/images/bg-phoenix.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dk9ru/)

I'd also suggest taking a look at [this recent SO answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127479/getting-the-height-of-a-background-image-resized-using-background-size-contain/21127924#21127924), which demonstrates how to get the height of the rendered background image, and scale the background accordingly:

[Getting the height of a background image resized using "background-size: contain"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127479/getting-the-height-of-a-background-image-resized-using-background-size-contain/21127924#21127924)

JS:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = $('body').css('background-image').replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");

$(window).on("resize", function () {
    $('body').height($('body').width() * img.height / img.width);
}).resize();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed info. It will help me understand it better.

Comment: How do I apply this element to pictures or is there another way of doing so??

Comment: @Jeiman What exactly do you mean? Are you referring to `img` elements?

Comment: Yes, inside divs and such. I have a couple of divs in which contains pictures in which i need to scale based on the width of the browser.

Comment: @Jeiman If you prepare a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net), i'll take a look at it. Generally, for responsive `img` elements, you would use `width:100%; height:auto` to maintain the aspect ratio of the element. This of course depends on the parent element.

Comment: Here you go: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2wGw4/). I tried your theory of having a `width:100%;` and `height:auto;` to maintain the aspect ratio, but it scales way too big on certain widths and it could be annoying to readers who read the website. Your thoughts on this?

Comment: @Jeiman Wouldn't that be the expected result? I'd suggest using media queries to change the layout per screen size. So for instance, on mobile devices with a limited width of under `480px`, you would use a one column layout as in that example. Anything greater than that would go to another layout which would then have a parent with a reduced width; maybe a 2 column layout for instance.

Comment: Ok, will try that out. Thanks again for the help. Really do appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3):

We can try background-size: 100% 100%; to fix it.

```
body {
    background: url("http://responsive.gs/images/bg-phoenix.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the code from the example you can use it in a page like so:

```
<head>
<style>
body
{
  background: url("http://www.responsive.gs/images/bg-phoenix.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
</body>
```