# Getting the size of a resized BG image

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div with a background image, which size is set to `contain`:

```
.image{
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    background-image: url('image_url');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Large images are being "scaled down" to fit in that div. I want to get the width and height of the image **AFTER** it was scaled down by `background-size: contain;`

I tried to do the following:

```
var myImg, frame;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onload);
function onload() {
    myImg= document.getElementById('image');
    frame = document.getElementById('frame');

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = window.getComputedStyle(myImg).getPropertyValue("background-image").replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");
    img.onload = function() {
        var imgHeight = img.height;
        console.log(imgHeight);
    }
}
```

The problem is I'm getting the size of the actual image, not the resized one. Can it be done? Also, I need to use plain vanilla JS, not jQuery or any other library...

Comment: You could take another approach and instead of getting the image dimensions you could calculate them yourself. Since you have the image dimensions and the div dimensions, this shouldn't be to hard.

Comment: @Fester Perhaps shouldn't be, but I'm having a few troubles with that... Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Have a look at this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127479/getting-the-height-of-a-background-image-resized-using-background-size-contain