# Centering content in a flex box with a background using 'background-size: contain'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

To begin, [here is a Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/w5e7c93n/2/).

What I am attempting to do is center the content (i.e. the `h1` and `h2`) with a flex box that scales to the current size of the background image.  Based on my own attempts, I'm assuming this will have to be a JavaScript solution (e.g., I'll have to calculate the size of the background image post-scaling), but I'd certainly welcome any type of solution at all.

I suppose the most succinct way to ask this is: How does one center content on an element using `background-size: contain`?

Other general questions I have:

1. What's the **best** method for calculating the dimensions of a background-image, regardless of what `background-size` property it is using?
2. Would something other than a flex box be better at centering content for this specific scenario? It's easy enough to center things when using `cover` but this seems like a whole new ball game.
3. Is it possible to make the flex-container (denoted by the red border) match the size and constraints of the background-image with pure CSS? Note that I ultimately want this to be responsive and am not necessarily looking to define static heights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear of what you really trying to achieve but I suspect you've just missed:

```
background-position:50% 50%;
```

Check: http://jsfiddle.net/farc8h1d/

1. answer is "no such method in principle".
2. `<center>` is still not reproducible by CSS means in full.
3. for defining width/height ratios by solely CSS see, for example,
   this:
   http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

Update: I think that I've got an idea of what you need. Here is another try: http://jsfiddle.net/6bzzj3j9/4/

Basic idea: to use `<img>` with `width:100% ; height:auto;` that defines size of its container. Text is inscribed in that container using position absolute.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  View this Fiddle in Chrome (https://jsfiddle.net/w5e7c93n/12/) to see what I want. For some reason, it only works in Chrome.

Comment: I actually solved this using a JavaScript method, but this seems really good too and I plan to investigate your pure CSS solution.  Thanks for the update.

Comment: Well, by solving layout problems with JS you are entering dark side of the Force.

Comment: I agree. Interestingly, I just checked your updated Fiddle again and it only works in Firefox, not Chrome. Is there something terribly wrong with my Chrome?

Comment: It works in Chrome for me here. In fact I do not see what couldn't work there.

Answer (score 0):

[This Fiddle is actually the behavior I was looking for.](https://jsfiddle.net/w5e7c93n/12/) The JavaScript was furnished by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127479/getting-the-height-of-a-background-image-resized-using-background-size-contain).

However, the it only seems to work properly in Chrome; not Firefox or Internet Explorer. I'm investigating but that should better provide insight into what I'm trying to do.

**Code:**

```
var img = new Image();
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("section-1")[0];
img.src = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("background-image").replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");

function resize() {
    var bgHeight = elem.offsetWidth * img.height / img.width;
    elem.style.height = bgHeight + 'px';
}
window.onresize = resize;
resize();
```