# Get the viewed dimensions of a background image

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I want to get the **displayed** dimensions of a CSS `background-image` when it is resized using CSS3 `background-size` property.

The web is filled with solutions to get the native/original width or height like this one -
[How do I get background image size in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106243/how-do-i-get-background-image-size-in-jquery)

I know that I can get the value of background size with `.css('background-size')` and use regex to extract the width and height but that does not work if `cover`, percentage values or `auto` is used.

Comment: can you provide any link of this page.

Comment: Can't you just use the dimensions of the container of the background? Or do you want to know the dimensions of the visible image + whats possible cropped?

Comment: @A.Jesin i think your comment got cropped? ;)

Comment: @NicoO Sometimes the background image is resized smaller than the container and sometimes it is resized to a larger size. I want to know the **rendered** size of the background image. A simple code is available here - http://jsfiddle.net/jesin/gC77n/

Comment: Have you seen this discussion? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106243/how-do-i-get-background-image-size-in-jquery

Comment: @TimSPQR That discussion shows how to get the __original__ dimensions, what I want is the size of the background image resized using `background-size`