# i have div and i want to set div height dependent on background-image height

Tags: javascript, css

I have a dynamic JS code that changes the background image of `div` on each click. How can I change `div` height and width dependent on the image size?

Here is my code for better understanding my problem:

```
element.style {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../wp-content/uploads/ssf-wp-uploads/images/24/image.jpg") no-repeat scroll center center;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here I set a fix size `150px` but background image size can change. So I want to set `div` height depending on background image height .

Comment: Changing the size of the div is likely to break the layout of your page...are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: actually i am working on map and open a a pop-up information after click on each marker ..

Comment: I'm not sure what that means or how it's relevant. Are you opening different pop-ups every time each with their own bg image?

Comment: What about just using a `<img>` with the url of the background image? It resizes automatically... (and you can still apply css filters and stuff to it)

Comment: yes i change the BG image on each pop-up . the BG image size not fix . that's why i am asking . look here for more clear .

Comment: <div id="info-img" class="info-img" data-template="modal-photo-viewer" data-plugins="open-modal" ')'="" style="position: relative; cursor: pointer; height: 150px; background: transparent url("../wp-content/uploads/ssf-wp-uploads/images/24/image1.jpg") no-repeat scroll center center;"></div>

Comment: here i fix 150px height for div . but my background image may be big or small so i want set this div height depend on BG image

Comment: Have a look at this solution: [How to get div height to auto-adjust to background size?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600743/how-to-get-div-height-to-auto-adjust-to-background-size

Comment: yes but not what i want . because that code unless using img tag . if i am using img tag . no need to background image . i am using bg image and can't change it ..

Comment: Do you mean to say you don't want to use the _img_ tag?

Comment: yes right . i want use only bg image

Comment: One quick suggestion would be to scale down your image and place it in your fix size div....So your div size need not be dynamic and gui looks perfect,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.elementstyle{
        background-image: url('http://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/articles/1111/large/feline-influenza-all-about-cat-flu-5239fffd61ddf.jpg');
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;

}
```

**In jQuery:**

```
var img= $('img');

img.removeAttr("width");
img.removeAttr("height");

var img_width = img.width();
var img_height = img.height();

$('.elementstyle').width(img_width).height(img_height);
```

**Edit:** I've just noticed that you're asking to get the size of the background image from the CSS. The method above would grab attributes from:

```
<div class="elementstyle"><img src=""/></div>
```

You'll have to look into defining the size of the background-image within jQuery. [Here's some reading material.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106243/how-do-i-get-background-image-size-in-jquery)

Comment: can u please change in my code . actually i don't have more knowledge about css

Comment: Done. Obviously wrap the jQuery in <script> tags.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned that you want to get *div* height to auto-adjust to background image, Note that, A background image has no effect on the size of the *div* it is declared in.

```
div{
    background-image: url('http://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/articles/1111/large/feline-influenza-all-about-cat-flu-5239fffd61ddf.jpg');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 66.64%; /* (img-height / img-width * container-width) */
                /* (853 / 1280 * 100) */
}
```

This is a trick to make a background image work like a *img*. For a better understanding on how the size of the image should be known before hand, I recommend reading the author's answer in detail along with the comments here: [How to get div height to auto-adjust to background size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600743/how-to-get-div-height-to-auto-adjust-to-background-size)