# Animate background-size width or height

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, background-size

How do I use JQuery's `animate()` on the background size of a div if I were to change either the width or the height, but not both.

For example, if I wanted to change the width, would something like the following work?

```
$("#buttonPic").animate({
    backgroundSizeW: "-=20px",
});
```

I could not find a similar question to this on SO

Comment: Can you make fiddle for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have doubts about `backgroundSizeW` property, seems a bit invalid to me:

```
$("#buttonPic").animate({
    backgroundSize: "-=20px auto"  // <-----it should work
});
```

Comment: yep it does work, but I was wondering if I can change only width not width and height. Something similar to this is possible with `background-position`, one can do `backgroundPositionX` with animate and it works

Comment: @Bolboa why don't you set that `auto` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The `.animate()` function can be used as follows

```js
$( "#go" ).click(function() {
  $( "#block" ).animate({
    width: "200px",
    }, 1500 );
});
```

```css
div {
    background-color: #bca;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="go">&raquo; Run</button>
<div id="block">Hello!</div>
```

Comment: This will not work, I want to change only the width of the background image for my div, not the div itself...Currently the divs background-size is set to `60px 60px`

Answer (score 0):

You can [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) background width height with `background-size`

```
$( "#buttonPic" ).click(function() {
  $( "#divBlock" ).animate({
    "background-size": "-=20px",
    }, 1500 );
});
```

Comment: I did not down vote, but this will work only if I want to change both width and height of `background-size`, currently it is set to `background-size: 60px 60px`, I want to change only one of these attributes, not both

Comment: Can you write html also? you should check http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: I don't see why it would be necessary, but here... `<button id="buttonPic">Add a photo</button>`

Comment: `background-size` works with `width` and `height` if you give it both. get one with jquery and set both.

Comment: You should check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106243/how-do-i-get-background-image-size-in-jquery?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,You can change the idea,for example:

```
$("#buttonPic").animate({
    backgroundSize: "40px 60px",
});
```

if you want the 'width' is a 'variable',you can set a width to istead the fixed value;just:

```
var wid=60;
wid-=20;
```