# How get responsive background image size while resize background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<div>` with background image like that:

```
#container {
    background-image: url("../img/bg.jpg");
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

and I have div with Id container

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Here is my css:

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    max-width: 1960px;
    max-height: 1960px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url("../img/bg.jpg");
    background-size:100% auto;
}
```

When i resize browser window my background image scaled too of course, and I want to get height of actual scaled size of my background image with pure js or j query how to do that?

**jsfiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/cihanzzzz/nqvjLpg9/1/

Comment: Can you provide some demo at jsfiddle?

Comment: Have you tried `background-size: contain;`?

Comment: i need to use backgroun size with cover for see all image in any dimension

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery like this to get the size of your container:

```
$('#container').height()
```

**UPDATE:**

To get the size of the background image inside your div, you should follow the steps on Vilius Paulauskas answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106243/how-do-i-get-background-image-size-in-jquery)

Comment: it's give to me height of container but i want to get height of background image because background image height change with browser resize

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106243/how-do-i-get-background-image-size-in-jquery) has the answer on how to do that

Comment: i already look at that here is showing absolute size of bg image i want to get actual size of background image when resize window

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of what I think you are trying to achieve.

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");

var listener = function (evt) {
  var newRect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
  // you could subtract any bounding padding or margin to get image height
  var newHeight = newRect.height;
  // you could subtract any bounding padding or margin to get image width
  var newWidth = newRect.width;
  
  console.log("new height", newHeight);
  console.log("new width", newWidth);
}

document.body.addEventListener("resize", listener);
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  max-width: 1960px;
  max-height: 1960px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
   background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532976845185-2d8b3fabc79b?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=81a3a29ef330765143527434a0312e7f&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80");
    background-size:100% auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```